# Proof $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)^a}$ < $\frac{1}{a-1} - \frac{1}{(a-1)(n+1)^{a-1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I also know that $\frac{1}{a-1} - \frac{1}{(a-1)(n+1)^{a-1}}$ = $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(a-1)k^{a-1}} - \frac{1}{(a-1)(k+1)^{a-1}} $

Any hint or help to solve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you would have to show: $\dfrac{1}{(k+1)^{a}} < \dfrac{1}{(a-1)k^{a - 1}} - \dfrac{1}{(a-1)(k+1)^{a - 1}}\iff a-1 < (k+1)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{k}\right)^{a-1}-k-1\iff a < (k+1)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{k}\right)^{a-1} - k$, and this can be done by induction on $k \geq 1$, assume that $a > 1$.

Comment: what is done by induction?

Comment: I am not allowed to use the rule of the solution below, but I need to understand your solution

Comment: why did you write -k-1 ? where the inequality in this?

Comment: -k-1 isn't an inequality to write <=> after it, are you sure there is no something missing?

Comment: I don't think I missed any thing here because I checked it several times.

Comment: the comma before -k-1 made me lost it, but i just get it thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\gt0$ and $a\ne1$, then $\frac1{x^a}$ is a decreasing function and so
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(k+1)^a}
&\le\int_1^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^a}\\
&=\frac1{a-1}\left(1-\frac1{(n+1)^{a-1}}\right)
\end{align}
$$